# Выборка SELECT в зависимости от условия в IF-THEN-ELSE

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, mariadb

В Microsoft SQL Server я легко могу выполнить следующий запрос:

```
declare @a tinyint
set @a = 1

if @a = 1
  select count(a) from Table

else
  select * from Table
```

То есть в зависимости от значения локальной переменной `@a` я могу вернуть разные датасеты. Полдня изучаю документацию по MariaDB/MySQL и ищу примеры, но аналогичной реализации найти не могу.

Возможна ли такая функциональность в MariaDB/MySQL?

Comment: Через процедуры можете

Comment: В MySQL нет анонимных блоков кода.